# Having issue with tan(7pi/6) converting degrees then to radical

Tags: trigonometry, radicals

I'm trying to work out the following problem:

```
tan 7pi / 6
```

I first converted `radians` to `degrees` and got `210`

`tan(210 degrees) = 0.577350`

How do I convert this to a radical? I'm having a hard time doing this.

Comment: Why go to degrees ?.  And even if you do that, $\frac{7\pi}{6}$ should be $180 + 30 = 210$ degrees.

Comment: $7\pi/6 $ radians $= (7/6)(180^{\circ})=210^{\circ}$

Comment: I just started trig, learning all this. Thank you guys.

Comment: [Radian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) not [radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical).

Comment: @Shailesh I fixed my mistake in the question, 210 degrees.

Comment: You have not fixed the line after that.... and the place where it says radical instead of radians.

Comment: Maybe OP really _does_ mean "radical". The tangent of $7\pi/6$ is expressible as the square root of a rational number, no? -- Looking at comments on the answer, now, evidently that _is_ what OP wants.

Comment: @DavidK Yeah. I just got confused when i got back decimals but answer is expected to be radical. Couldn't find a straight forward way to convert from decimal to radical. Then the answer posted shows 2 steps and honestly since i'm still a bit uneasy with the unit circle, the answer he got `1/sqrt(3)`, while correct, i don't understand it. But anyway, this is going outside the scope of the original question - "0.577350 How do I convert this to a radical?" :) Which is what i got after getting the tan of 210 degrees.

Comment: Radicals aren't a unit, so you don't convert to them. So you can understand the confusion.

Comment: @Naga The unfortunate answer is that there is no foolproof way to convert a decimal to a radical, because for any given decimal you can write, there are a lot of radicals that round off to the same decimal. If you are lucky, you might guess the right one. The better way to do this is to learn the frequently-used exact sines, cosines, and tangents around the unit circle. I know that's not yet comfortable but that's the point: I think the purpose of exercises like this is to push you to _become_ comfortable with it.

Comment: @DavidK Sounds like it, at the moment is foggy but it will kick in sooner or later ^_^,  Thank you everyone for clearing this up! I will start learning the common used sin/cos/tan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\tan$ is a periodic function with period $\pi$, then
$$\tan \left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right)=\tan \frac{\pi}{6}=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}$$

Comment: I guess my question should be.. How do you end up with that answer? In the calculator if i set it to degrees and do `tan(pi/6)` i'm getting a decimal, how do i convert this decimal to `1/sqrt(3)`

Comment: Switch your calculator to the mode Math, maybe it will display an alternative form: $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$. 

If your calculator does not have Math mode you only can verify the answer by introducing $1\div\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: This problem does not require a calculator. Use a [table of trigonometric values for common angles](http://www.math.com/tables/trig/tables.htm). $\frac{\pi}{6}$ is very well-known.

Comment: @shoover Thank you for this